# Flash of activity with dark background while created

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity with bark background launched as `singleInstanse`, and when it's starts the first time it has a shot white flash (white background shown) before showing its content. How can I prevent that? Or may be it is possible set up activity's default background color at start? Thanks.

Comment: Try using the `Theme.Material` theme in your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to what is called the ***preview window*** during app launching.

A very clear explanation of the issue and how to get around it is given by [Cyril Mottier in android-app-launching-made-gorgeous](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/)

Answer (score 0):

your app theme should have background color... thid color will replace the dark screen.